# Zeppelin println just outputs the code?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When I put a println statement, it just outputs the code. What idiotic thing am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What is your default interpreter? If it's spark/scala it will print out "test" as you'd expect.

Comment: Yup, default is spark/scala.

Comment: @Phasmid, you're right. I was being an idiot and unchecked the binding to spark/scala. Zeppelin's interface for interpreter binding should be more clear on what's bound and what's not. Blue/white tags ain't the most intuitive what's on and what's not to a newcomer.

Comment: yeah, there are a few things like that in Zeppelin which can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default interpreter to spark (scala) or set it for the paragraph explicitly with %spark.