# Scala println() in zeppelin paragraph doesn't print while regular print() prints well

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

On zeppelin notebook, with **working** spark/scala interpreter, I'm trying to do the simplest task:

```
println("Hello World");
```

And when I run it, I get blank (nothing!) in the output part.
On the other hand, when I'm only using

```
print("Hello World");
```

Without the *ln*, it prints OK.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What else do you have in that paragraph?

Comment: Nothing, just plain prints on both cases.

Comment: This is probably an interpretation issue in Zeppelin; it might just show the current line in its output. Take a look at `stdout`/ `stderr`, the output should be there as expected.

Comment: @Sai In the console where I run zeppelin, I see a: "Receive message from RemoteInterpeter Process", with a RemoteInterpeterEvent with type:OUTPUT_APPEND which contains the println result. Although I can see it, it is not ideal and make the development very hard. Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553730/zeppelin-println-just-outputs-the-code)

Comment: @user3190018 No, it does not print the _code_, it prints nothing - blank.

Answer (score 1):

To me this look related to the stdout being in the driver or executors, and not about the specific instruction used (because in that case would be really odd).

At least my zeppelin instance (i'm on EMR) is only printing statement that are in the stdout on the driver, so is important WHERE your prints are.

I had a similar issue but it was because my print was inside a dataframe foreach, hence executed in the executors and not in the driver.

For example:

```
val dataset = spark.read.parquet(...)

println("This will be appeard")

dataset.foreach(println(_))
 //you won't see this since the print will happen in the executors


dataset.take(1).foreach(println(_))
//you should see this since happen in the driver after collecting the result
```

Try to see if you are doing something like that.